# "more than one does" or "more than one do"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> However, if no x satisfies the equation or more than one x does—that
>   is the solution is not unique—the problem is said not to be well
>   posed.

In the line(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization)) above it uses "more than one does", but logically and intuitively it should be "more than one do" since "more than one" means two or more, then it is plural. I have tried my best to interpret it as it is, but hardly can I convince myself to make "more than" collocate with "does" as an adv., which may only make it make sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your logic is impeccable; unfortunately [the convention is to use "more than one *does*"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=more+than+one+does+%2C+more+than+one+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) even if it's technically a plural.

Digging deeper, I found [this from the American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=more+or+less)

> When a noun phrase contains more than one and a singular noun, the verb is normally singular: *More than one editor is working on that project*. *More than one field has been planted with oats*. When more than one is followed by of and a plural noun, the verb is plural: *More than one of the paintings were stolen*. *More than one of the cottages are for sale*. When more than one stands alone, it usually takes a singular verb, but it may take a plural verb if the notion of multiplicity predominates: *The operating rooms are all in good order. More than one is (or are) equipped with the latest imaging technology.*

Again, I'd say this is more *convention* than *rule*, but it's still a good idea to follow.

Answer (score -2):

The basic structure, you would want to note when such doubt arises, is what subject is the verb describing. Here, In conditional phrase under question, `x` is the subject- satisfying of the equation by x. So, the question is whether or not, x satisfies the equation? Therefore, only set of option you are left with is `x does` or `x does not`. Both are the singular form of verbs.